# What is the best way to separate out a few column from an existing table into a new table while maintaining relationship?

Tags: sql, postgresql, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

Let's say that I have a table Payment with the following columns

```
    payment_id - UUID
    amount - Numeric
    order_id - Unique VARCHAR
    psp_order_id - Third Party Unique Order Id created by Payment Service Provider
    psp_payment_id -Third Party Unique Payment Id created by Payment Service Provider
    created_at - payment created at
    ended_at - payment ended at
```

Now there is a requirement for integrating a new PSP.
But since the Payment table is tightly bound to one PSP, I would like to move psp_order_id, psp_payment_id to another table Eg: razorpay_payment_details.

So the resulting schema could be :

**Payment Table**

```
    payment_id - UUID
    amount - Numeric
    order_id - Unique VARCHAR
    created_at - payment created at
    ended_at - payment ended at
```

**razorpay_payment_details**

```
    id - UUID (Primary Key)
    psp_order_id (Unique String)
    psp_payment_id (Unique String)
    payment_id (Foreign Key which relates Payment Entity to razorpay_payment_details entity)
```

How should one go about changing the schema and migrating the existing production data into the new table ?

Technologies used - Spring Boot, PostgreSQL
PS: I do not manage Database Migrations using Flyway/Liquibase.

Comment: Which version of Postgresql you are using

Comment: Can you say more about "Payment table is tightly bound to one PSP"? It's worth googling "inheritance in relational databases", there are a few other options. It may not make sense to require adding a payment processor (a common-ish business event) require a whole new database table, with all the work that goes with that...

Comment: Creating a new table is not a good idea, any time you do you introduce synchronization issues and this inevitably to data inconsistency.  Since you new data requirement is a sub-set of the existing table just create a VIEW.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your steps with query will be like this:

Create your table `razorpay_payment_details` first:

```
create table razorpay_payment_details(
id uuid DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4 (),
  psp_order_id varchar(100),
  psp_payment_id varchar(100),
  payment_id uuid,
  primary key(id),
  constraint fk_paymentid
  foreign key(payment_id)
  references payment(payment_id)
)
```

Migrate your data from `payment` table to new table `razorpay_payment_details` using below query:

```
insert into razorpay_payment_details (psp_order_id, psp_payment_id, payment_id)

select psp_order_id, psp_payment_id, payment_id from payment
```

After completion of migration and verification of data you can run below query to alter he `payment` table:

```
alter table payment 
drop column psp_order_id ,
drop column psp_payment_id;
```

**Do'nt forget to take backup before this activity**

Answer (score 0):

You would typically create the new table (`razorpay_payment_details`), and then copy the relevant rows/columns from the original table (`payment`) with an `insert ... select` query.

```
insert into razorpay_payment_details(psp_order_id, psp_payment_id, payment_id)
select psp_order_id, psp_payment_id, payment_id from payment;
```

The `id` column should an automatically generated column (such as a `serial` column), so I left it apart in the query.

You can then go ahead with the validation of the results. Finally, you can drop the columns from the original table.

```
alter table payment 
    drop column psp_order_id,
    drop column psp_payment_id;
```